# C: Last element of an array using a list

Tags: c, arrays, list, struct

I have these functions that I am using to make a convex boundary from a set of ordered pairs. If anyone is familiar with Graham's Scan then I am sure it will help with understanding the nature of these functions. Regardless, there are descriptions to what each of the functions are intended to do.

I do not think that `popBack` works correctly and I put the other two functions for some feedback. Suggestions on how to fix `popBack` and other possible errors are welcomed.

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
 } point;

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    int capacity;
    point *values;
} list;


// Remove the last item from the list
void popBack(list *p)
{
    int x;
    if (p->size > 0){
        x = p->size - 1;
        p->values[x] = p->values[x + 1];
    }
}

// Return the last item from the list
point getLast(list *p)
{
    point value;
    value = p->values[p->size];
    return value;
}

// Return the next to the last item
point getNextToLast(list *p)
{
    point value;
    value = p->values[p->size - 1];
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the question is?

Comment: What if the size is 0? It would reference `p->values[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a `pop` function would remove the item on the end of the list and, in addition, return it. Otherwise you could simply implement it as

```
void popBack(list *p) {
    if (p->size == 0)
        return;
    p->size--;
}
```

If you want to return a value then:

```
point popBack(list *p) {
    int indexLast = p->size - 1; /* index of the last element in the list */
    if (indexLast < 0)
        return 0; /* error */
    p->size = indexLast;         /* also happens to be the new size after one element is removed */
    return p[indexLast];
}
```

At the moment the reason why your code probably isn't doing what it's supposed to be doing is because this line:

```
    p->values[x] = p->values[x + 1];
```

takes the last element of the list, and assigns instead the value of the *element after the last element*, which is problematic for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with `popBack`**

You just need to decrement the size of the list. Your function does not make any sense at all. All you need in the function is:

```
void popBack(list *p)
{
    p->size--;
}
```

BTW, it is customary to return the item that got popped. You should change the function to:

```
point popBack(list *p)
{
    p->size--;
    return p->values[p->size];
}
```

**Problem with `getLast`**

You are returning the wrong item. If `size` is equal to 1, you need to return the first item from the list -- i.e. `p->values[0]` not `p->values[1]`

The function can be simplified to:

```
point getLast(list *p)
{
    return p->values[p->size-1];
}
```

**Problem with `getNextToLast`**

Following the change to `getLast`, this function needs to return `p->values[p->size-2]`. It can be simplified to:

```
point getNextToLast(list *p)
{
    return p->values[p->size - 2];
}
```

**Miscellaneous**

You have to introduce checks to make sure that you don't access the array `p->values` out of bounds. Otherwise, it will be easy to run into undefined behavior.